# Save iptables DD-WRT command

Tags: iptables

I am trying to save an ip-blocking rule in DD-WRT but without success, every time I reboot the router the rule disappears. I wanted to save the rule permanently. I entering the GUI going under Administration> Commands this works, but I want to save this in SSH

v3.0-r39469 std (04/10/19)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with iptables-save and iptables-restore.

Source:

https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=174011

https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Firewall_Builder

Comment: `iptables-save` is outdated it seems. Firewall builder is probably the option to go.